# Regex for validating constant field with numbers

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I am trying for a regex pattern matching for my input. My requirement is that my input should strictly adhere to the following format

```
CHECK ID@<number>
```

(Eg. my input should be CHECK ID@3213)

How do i frame the pattern for this?

Comment: It is not clear what number means. Is it always positive integer? Is it always four digits? Or more allowed? Is it supposed to check whether the entire string exactly matches that pattern, or is is okay if the string includes that pattern? Is it supposed to return true or false, or is it supposed to extract some portion? In short, the expected output is not shown. And only one side of input is shown (**inferring** that the given one is a matching pattern, a non-matching example is not shown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the ID number use this

```
"CHECK ID@123".scan(/CHECK ID@(\d+)/).last.first.to_i # => 123
```

Because you just need one result there is not need to use `.scan` or `.match`

```
"CHECK ID@123"[/CHECK ID@(\d+)/, 1].to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
match = "CHECK ID@1221".match /^CHECK ID@(\d+)$/
puts match[1] if match
=> 1221
```